Have 0-10v sink dimmer change it to source dimmer
I am discovering that a 0-10v dimming comes in two flavors - sink and source, depending on who originates the voltage source.
I have an expensive light fixture for which I was told a 0-10v sink dimmer would work. Unfortunately they were wrong, it requires a source dimmer (LF-GLD065YS from Lufid).  I bought a Shelly 0-10v dimmer (described here: enter link description here) which is a sink. Doesn't work.
I'm struggling to find a similar style smart 0-10v dimmer that is a source, i.e. one I can put in a box and control via wifi and z-wave with home assistant. Note talking just the dimmer part, not the LED driver, those are built into the fixture (that LF part number).
I expected to find some kind of adapter that could convert a sink version to a source - I have not.  Can I build something, say a 12v power supply and some resisters and... what?
I'm also delighted to buy something equivalent that is a source, if someone has that as an alternative solution, but can I build an adapter?
Update: 6/2/24 2209z: So I think I have been mislead by a defective Shelly 0-10v dimmer. While doing further testing I found a change in behavior depending on position, I could tip it one way vs another and the behavior changed. Checked connections (good), disassembled, nothing obvious, re-assembled and at least so far it is actually working. I have a dimmer that is at least a source (+11v by meter with nothing hooked up) and one that is a sink (0v with nothing hooked up). Both work with the light, so either the driver is auto-sense or the source dimmer is also auto-sensing.  Regardless, my "sink" now works (though this dimmer gets discarded since it is clearly broken -- or was and I didn't actually do a repair).
I still have an intellectual curiosity how I could fix it, but no longer have an issue.
Linwood

Please edit your question title to clarify your question:  do you want to know how to make your sink dimmer substitute for a source dimmer?  (If so, please give model and link to data sheet.)  For your alternate question: you seem to know a bit about this technology.  If you propose a specific model (with link to specs) that will meet your needs provided it is the source type, someone may be able to assist you in assessing whether it is indeed a source type.

OK, I tried, additional advice welcomed.

So to confirm: you have fixtures which dim with ESTA E1.3 inputs and you can only find IEC Standard 60929 Annex E outputs for the type of dimmer you want to use?

I'm sorry, a brief search did not educate me, the first reference is behind a paywall (at least what I could find), the second sent me around in circles.  What I THOUGHT I had was a driver that did not source voltage (because a dumb dimmer included with it did), and a smart dimmer I knew was only a sink.  It appears however that the LED driver either is a source, or auto-detect.  My "sink" dimmer was simply not functioning properly.  So my actual problem is solved, though I have an intellectual curiosity if it was actually as I thought, could it be easily solved? I have updated the main post.

It is possible to convert between ESTA E1.3 and IEC Standard 60929 Annex E dimming. The circuit is even relatively simple. There are commercial products available which convert between the two standards, most commonly in the direction to allow theatrical ESTA E1.3 dimmers to control architectural lighting. There are also devices that go either and both ways to or from DMX. DMX tends to end up being the Swiss army knife of standards for this sort of conversion, and often the easiest way to handle multiple kinds of lights is to have all your controls talk DMX (or a DMX over Ethernet format such as Artnet). Then you can use appropriate dimmer types for each type of fixture.

Any chance you could share a pointer to, or diagram of the conversion circuit.  As mentioned above at this point it is more curiosity than needing it since I found the faulty equipment was my issue not such a need.

Here is a complicated automatic way that someone has patented: https://patents.google.com/patent/US20190059141A1/en

And here is some discussion about how to do it with simpler circuits: https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/0-10vdc-sinking-voltage-output.139219/

And to think I might have violated a patent if I actually had to build something.  :)  Thank you for the links.
